# Ionic 2 BLE disconnect callback/subscribe

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, subscribe

I get this error when trying to subscribe to the disconnect callback.

```
this.ble.disconnect(this.device_id).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("disconnected good");
}, error => {
  console.log("disconnected bad");
});
```

the error I get is this

```
 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
 L116:  if (this.device_id) {
 L117:      this.ble.disconnect(this.device_id).subscribe((data) => {
 L118:              console.log("disconnected good");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disconnect`-function returns a `Promise` not an `Observable` ([docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/#disconnect)).

Try this instead:

```
this.ble.disconnect(this.device_id)
.then(data => {
    console.log("disconnected good");
}
.catch(error => {
    console.log("disconnected bad");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
this.ble.disconnect(this.device_id).then(() => {
  console.log('Disconnected');
});
```

Comment: Yes thats what my answer said.

Comment: Thanks @robbannn :) I missed your answer. You rock.